# Scheduling ToneJS events while transport is playing

Tags: javascript, node.js, tone.js

I have 4 notes playing in my Tone JS app and would like to change the 3rd note to be something else whilst the transport is currently playing. Here is my code:

JS:

```
import { Transport, start, Sampler } from "tone";

const notesToPlay = [
  {
    timing: 0.25,
    sameAsLast: false,
    duration: 0.1,
    velocity: 1
  },
  {
    timing: 0.5,
    sameAsLast: true,
    duration: 0.1,
    velocity: 1
  },
  {
    timing: 0.75,
    sameAsLast: false,
    duration: 0.1,
    velocity: 1
  },
  {
    timing: 1,
    sameAsLast: false,
    duration: 0.2,
    velocity: 1
  }
];

var eventIds = [];

(function () {
  function playSynth() {
    Transport.start();
    start();
  }

  const sampler = new Sampler({
    urls: {
      A1: "A1.mp3",
      A2: "A2.mp3"
    },
    baseUrl: "https://tonejs.github.io/audio/casio/",
    onload: () => {
      loadNotes();
    }
  }).toDestination();

  function loadNotes() {
    notesToPlay.forEach((n) => {
      const eventId = Transport.scheduleRepeat((time) => {
        sampler.triggerAttackRelease(
          ["A1"],
          n.duration,
          n.timing + time,
          n.velocity
        );
      }, 4);

      eventIds.push(eventId);
    });
  }

  document.getElementById("play").addEventListener("click", function () {
    playSynth();
  });

  document.getElementById("stop").addEventListener("click", function () {
    Transport.stop();
  });

  document.getElementById("replace").addEventListener("click", function () {
    const arrayIdxToReplace = 2;
    Transport.clear(eventIds[arrayIdxToReplace]);
    const note = notesToPlay[arrayIdxToReplace];
    Transport.scheduleRepeat((time) => {
      sampler.triggerAttackRelease(
        ["D1"],
        note.duration,
        note.timing + time,
        note.velocity
      );
    }, 4);
  });
})();
```

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <button id="play">play me</button>
  <button id="stop">stop</button>
  <button id="replace">Replace 3rd note</button>
</div>
```

When I click the replace 3rd note button it removes the old event which is good but when it schedules the new event in it is out of sync with where the old 3rd note would be.

A way to get around this is by stopping the Transport then clicking to replace the 3rd note and then clicking play again however I want to be able to do this while the Transport is still playing. Where have I gone Wrong?

Here is a fiddle to demo the issue:

https://codesandbox.io/s/tonejs-forked-fxhzm?file=/src/index.js:0-1643

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty awkward to fix the way it is structured now. The trouble is that every note you add is on its own loop, which begins whenever you call `scheduleRepeat` ... you would have to correct for the offset between the original loop and the new one, which seems kind of tricky.

I'd suggest that you have call `scheduleRepeat` only once, and have the callback read the list of notes you have stored. That way you can just replace or alter one of those notes and the next time around it'll be changed, and you won't have any timing problems. I think that would mean including the pitch in your note schema.

Comment: Is there any chance you could adjust the code sandbox to show what you mean? I tried amending as per your suggestion here: https://codesandbox.io/s/tonejs-forked-fxhzm?file=/src/index.js but there are two issues: 1. The loop seems to overlap with other loops 2. I am not seeing what method I would use here to replace/ alter one of the notes?

Comment: sure, how about this: https://codesandbox.io/s/tonejs-forked-9hs2y

Comment: Well, `scheduleRepeat` doesn't schedule notes you see, in schedules calls to the provided function. So that function will be called every 4 seconds, and it references your array every time.

Comment: I just saw it after I asked ;) thanks for your help